# OpenCV Neural network for images processing

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, neural-network, perceptron

I new in AI world and try some practice.
It looks like I need some third-party experience.

Let's say I need to get rid of image defects (actually the task more tricky).
I hope that trained NN will be able to interpolate defect area.

For these reasons I try to create simple neural network.
It has input : grayscale image with deffect(72*54) and the same image with no defect.
Hidden layer has 2*72*54 neurons.

Main piece of code

```
   cv::Ptr<cv::ml::ANN_MLP> ann = cv::ml::ANN_MLP::create();

   int inputsCount = imageSizes.width * imageSizes.height;
   std::vector<int> layerSizes = { inputsCount, inputsCount * 2, inputsCount};
   ann->setLayerSizes(layerSizes);
   ann->setActivationFunction(cv::ml::ANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM);

   cv::TermCriteria tc(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER + cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 50, 0.1);
   ann->setTermCriteria(tc);

   ann->setTrainMethod(cv::ml::ANN_MLP::BACKPROP, 0.0001);

   std::cout << "Result : " << ann->train(trainData, cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE, resData) << std::endl;
   ann->predict(trainData, predicted);
```

My training dataset looks like
[image]

Trained on 10 items dataset NN gives bad results on this(same) inputs. I tried different params 
[image]

But trained on only 2 images NN gets close output (on trained data).

[image]

I suppose that it's not inappropriate approach and solution is not so easy.

**Maybe someone has some advice about parameters or neural network architecture or whole approach.**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the termination criteria were fine for just two samples but were not good enough when training with a larger number of samples. Do try adjusting them, and also the learning rate.
Judging by the quality of the pixels that have been restored properly, the network architecture seems to be fine for this task. Once the network works well on 10 samples, I strongly recommend adding more training samples.

Answer (score 1):

The chief problem is that you have way to little data for the given network.

Your NN is fully connected. The weights for pixel 0,0 are entirely separate from those of pixel 1,0, and pixel 0,1 has again different weights. And you have a *lot* of weights, with so many nodes. So while you have plenty of pixels in 10 images, you have nowhere near enough pixels for all the weights.

A **Convolutional Neural Network** has far less weights, as many of its weights are reused. That means that in training, these weights are trained by multiple pixels from each training image.

Not that I'd expect this to work well with just 10 images. The human expectation is derived from years of human vision, literally billions of images.